# How do I replace a certrain char in a string of "****" with a char taken as input? Java

Tags: java

These are the instructions for the method:

```
// Given a character, a String containing a word, and a String containing a 'guess'
// for that word, return a new String that is a modified version of the 'guess' 
// string where characters equal to the character inChar are uncovered.
// For example, given the following call:
//   modfiyGuess('G',"GEOLOGY", "**O*O*Y")
// This functions should return the String "G*O*OGY".
```

Here is my code:

```
private static String modifyGuess(char inChar, String word, String currentGuess) {
    int count= 0;
    int occur= 0;
    while (count < word.length()-1)
    {
        if(!(word.charAt(count)== inChar)){

            count++;
        }
        else if(word.charAt(count)==inChar)
        {
            currentGuess= currentGuess.replace(currentGuess.charAt(count), inChar);
            occur++;
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The character " +inChar +" occurs in " +occur +" positions");
    System.out.println(" ");
    return currentGuess;
}
```

For some reason, if the char inChar is found in the string word, currentGuess is returned as a string like "GGGGGG", replacing all chars in the string with inChar, instead of returning something like "G****G*" 
Thank you for any answers you may have!

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Being in a hurry isn't a good excuse. Write the question when you have more time to do it correctly.

Comment: Hint, use StringBuilder...

Comment: Sorry, original post has been updated with a better explanation!

Comment: @MadProgrammer Out of curiosity, for something such as the code block that you made in your edit, is it better to instead use a blockquote? I thought that it is so because the block doesn't contain any code, just instructions.

Comment: @Quincunx Block quote tends not to maintain the formatting like code blocks, since it was comment code, I thought using the code formatting would result in a more readable format ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me I would elect to use a for loop as opposed to a while, it's really personal preference but because you'll need to iterate over the entire string it can be a little more intuitive and easier to understand for the reader when a for is used.

It also seems your if conditions are inverses of each other. You check if it is *not* equal to the char and then check if it *is*. Why not just check if it is, then you know it *isn't*. Here the string builder is used to, well build a string. If it is to be replaced it is and if not we append the result (names adjusted so you have to do *something* to use it.)

```
public static String modifyGuess(char letter, String word, String result) {
    int occurrences = 0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
        if(word.charAt(i) == letter) {
            builder.append(letter);
            occurrences++;
        } else {
            builder.append(result.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nThe character " + letter +" occurs in " + occurrences +" positions\n");
    return builder.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String word = "GEOLOGY";
    String result = "**OLO**";

    result = modifyGuess('G', word, result);
    System.out.println(result);
    result = modifyGuess('E', word, result);
    System.out.println(result);
    result = modifyGuess('Y', word, result);
    System.out.println(result);
}//SSCCE1
```

Output:

> The character G occurs in 2 positions
>
> G*OLOG*
>
> The character E occurs in 1 positions
>
> GEOLOG*
>
> The character Y occurs in 1 positions
>
> GEOLOGY

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback! I wasn't yet familiar with StringBuilder. It's a lot easier!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to achieve this.  The most important thing to remember is `String` is immutable, that is, it's contents can't be changed.

In your original code, you are using

```
currentGuess= currentGuess.replace(currentGuess.charAt(count), inChar);
```

Which, based on you example, would be like saying, replace "*" with "G", which results in `"GGOGOGY"`, not quite what you wanted.

Instead, you need to create a some kind of temporary location where you can build the new "guess" from, for example...

```
public static String modifyGuess(char inChar, String word, String currentGuess) {
    String newGuess = "";
    for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++) {
        if (word.charAt(index) == inChar) {
            newGuess += word.charAt(index);
        } else {
            newGuess += currentGuess.charAt(index);
        }
    }
    return newGuess;
}
```

Now, while this works, this has issues with creating lots of temporary `String` objects.  In a small, short lived, application this might not be an issue, but in large, longer running applications, this becomes a problem, as it can degrade performance over time, instead, you could do something...

```
public static String modifyGuess(char inChar, String word, String currentGuess) {
    char[] newGuess = new char[word.length()];
    for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++) {
        if (word.charAt(index) == inChar) {
            newGuess[index] = word.charAt(index);
        } else {
            newGuess[index] = currentGuess.charAt(index);
        }
    }
    return new String(newGuess);
}
```

This will only create a single new `String` each time it's created.  The only issue I might have with this, is it's possible that the `word` might be longer then `currentGuess`/  You can guard against this by changing `newGuess[index] = currentGuess.charAt(index);` with `newGuess[index] = "*"` for example...

Finally, my preferred method, would be to use `StringBuilder`, as this has the benefits of a `char` array, in that it won't create a lot of temporary `String`s, but with out the limitations of the `char` array, for example

```
public class GuessString {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(modifyGuess('G',"GEOLOGY", "**O*O*Y"));
    }

    public static String modifyGuess(char inChar, String word, String currentGuess) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(currentGuess);
        for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++) {
            if (word.charAt(index) == inChar) {
                sb.replace(index, index, Character.toString(inChar));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Basically, I take the `currentGuess` and create a copy of it using `StringBuilder`.  I then proceeded to perform the matching check, replacing the individual matches as I find them

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question. Correct me if I am wrong: You have a string that is the correct answer and a string of characters that represents the guesses so far. I assume "*" is a wildcard and means any letter. Please try to be more specific next time so we can answer quicker. Try this code (it works correctly with your example):

```
private static String modifyGuess(char inChar, String word, String currentGuess) {
    int occurences = 0;
    char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
    char[] guessArray = currentGuess.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < guessArray.length; i++) {
        if (guessArray[i] == '*') {
            if (wordArray[i] == inChar) {
                guessArray[i] = inChar;
                occurences++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The character " + inChar + " occurs in " + occurences + " positions.");
    System.out.println(" ");
    return new String(guessArray);
}
```

This solution gets the `char` array of both `word` and `currentGuess`. It then loops through the array or `currentGuess` and checks if the current character is a wildcard. If it is, it then checks if the same position in `word` is the same as `inChar`. That means the guess is correct for that character. It then updates the `guess` to change the wildcard to `inChar` and increments the occurences. You could also use a `StringBuilder`, but I'm not sure if you're allowed to.

By the way, the `String.replace(char, char)` replaces all "*" with "G", no matter where they are.

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: Rather then just dumping code on an unexpecting poster, you might like to explain why this solution is works and/or is better then other ways of achieving the same result - ps I do like that fact that you've done this manually, be there are some draw backs to this approach ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry. Hopefully my added explanation helps.

Comment: No worries, much nicer to "lead" then "drag" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Guess you're late on doing your homework?

```
//The StringBuilder lets you set a character at a given index
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(currentGuess);

//Let's look at every single character in word...
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    //If the character in word is equal to the character to be uncovered, ...
    if(word.charAt(i) == inChar) {
        //we change the character in the resulting word.
        b.setCharAt(i, inChar);
    }
}
//And return the result
return b.toString();
```

Comment: Rather then just dumping code on an unexpecting poster, you might like to explain why this solution is works and/or is better then other ways of achieving the same result

Comment: Feel free to do so, your comments won't help him either ;)

Comment: Thank you! I still have time to do it but I have a lot of stuff to do because I just got back from break. I just could not figure out why it was doing this

Comment: Yes this is basically hangman, but you have an unlimited number of guesses

Comment: @brickBreaker You actually don't need to type `java.lang.StringBuilder`, you only need to type `StringBuilder` for the same reason you don't have to type `java.lang.String`.